# How do I exclude an additional worksheet from this function?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro that copies two `Ranges` from every `wS` within a `wB` `<> "TT"` and sets corresponding `Ranges` in `wS AMT` to these `Ranges.`

The first `Range` from each `wS <> TT` is copied to Column B in `wS ATM` and appended to the first not blank cell in column B.

The second `Range` from each `wS <> TT` is copied into incrementally increasing columns in `wS ATM` this looks like this:

`ColumnD wS ATM = ColumnC Sheet3 
 ColumnE wS ATM = ColumnC Sheet4 
 ColumnF wS ATM = ColumnC Sheet5`

This **all** works correctly.

```
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim TT As Worksheet
 Dim AMT As Worksheet
 Dim Last As Long

 Set TT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tranche Tracker")
 Set ATM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Application Maturity Tracker")

 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If sh.Name <> TT.Name Then
         Last = WorksheetFunction.Max(4, TT.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
         sh.Range("B4:B10000").Copy TT.Range("B" & Last)
     End If
 Next

 TT.Range("B4:B10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

 End Sub
```

My problem is I want to exclude `wS AMT` as well as `wS TT`.

I've tried `If sh.Name <> TT.Name Or ATM.Name Then` which seems logically correctly but it doesn't do anything, nothing changes. I've tried a few variations of `and/or` logic but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm specifically just looking to exclude `wS ATM` as well as `wS TT`.

Comment: hi, just replace "If sh.Name <> TT.Name Then" to  "If sh.Name <> TT.Name OR  sh.Name <> ATM.Name Then ". good luck

Comment: Note that <> is "not equals" in VBA. To exclude both sheets, you need an `and`, like `If sh.Name <> TT.Name AND sh.Name <> ATM.Name`

Comment: U have right. My mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular, you could just do

```
 If sh.Name <> TT.Name and sh.Name <> ATM.Name Then
```

However, if you wanted to extend it to more sheets, you might want to consider using `Select Case`, viz:

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case sh.Name
        Case TT.Name, ATM.Name 'add as necessary
        'do nothing
        Case Else
            Last = WorksheetFunction.Max(4, TT.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            sh.Range("B4:B10000").Copy TT.Range("B" & Last)
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Note that in the first part of your answer, you would need an `and` instead of `or`, if you want to exclude both sheets